# How to update information on MKPinAnnotationView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate, mkpointannotation

I've had some past experience using `MKMapView` and `MKPointAnnotation`, which I used to put some pin on a map.
This time I am trying to go one step further and use `MKPinAnnotationView`, to write a label along with some of the pins.

Unfortunately, it doesn't all work as I expect.

Here is what I want to do:

I have a map (an MKMapView object) and when I touch it, I put a pin at the touch point, then some computation is performed and this gives me a second point on the map. I put a second pin on the map (located at the second point), on this last pin I want to put a label, say "Hello Second!", but this label needs to be updated when the pin changes place.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var mapView:MKMapView!, touchPoint,secondPoint:MKPointAnnotation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView = MKMapView()
        ...........
        let mapTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                            action: #selector(ViewController.mapTouchHandler))
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(mapTap)
    }


    func mapTouchHandler(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        ...........
        // Compute map coordinates for the touch point (tapGeoPoint).

        if touchPoint == nil {
            touchPoint = MKPointAnnotation()
            mapView.addAnnotation(touchPoint);
        }

        touchPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tapGeoPoint.latitude,
                                                       longitude: tapGeoPoint.longitude)
        ...........
        computeSecondPoint(url: someComputedURL)
    }


    func computeSecondPoint(url searchURL:String) {
        let reqURL = NSURL(string: searchURL)!, session = URLSession.shared,
        task = session.dataTask(with: reqURL as URL) {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            if error == nil {
                do {let allData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
                    .................
                    // Compute map coordinates for the second point (secondPointCoord).

                    if self.secondPoint == nil {
                        self.secondPoint = MKPointAnnotation()
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.secondPoint)
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        () -> Void in
                        self.secondPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: secondPointCoord.latitude,
                                                                             longitude: secondPointCoord.longitude)
                        self.secondPoint.title = "Hello Second -TITLE!"
                        //* I want to update the label for this pin (attached to the secondPoint) too.
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {print(error.localizedDescription)}
            } else {
                print("Error inside \(#function):\n\(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()

    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
                 viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let identifier = "pin"
        var view: MyPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
            as? MyPinAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MyPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

            if ((annotation.coordinate.latitude != touchPoint.coordinate.latitude) ||
                (annotation.coordinate.longitude != touchPoint.coordinate.longitude)) {//* I need a better test to check that this not touchPoint!
                view.pinTintColor = UIColor.blue
                view.canShowCallout = true
                view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -7, y: 0)
                view.setInfo(title: "Hi Start Label!")
            } else {
                view.pinTintColor = UIColor.red
                view.canShowCallout = false
            }
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Here is the class MyPinAnnotationView:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MyPinAnnotationView: MKPinAnnotationView {
    let information:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 70.0, height: 30.0)))

    func setInfo(title : String)
    {
        information.text = title
        information.textAlignment = .center
        self.addSubview(information)
    }


    func hideInfo() {
        information.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

The lines with a comment marked //*, show where I need some help.

- First issue, I want to update the label on the secondPoint, but I don't know what code to use. Line:

  //* I want to update the label for this pin (attached to the secondPoint) too.

Now the label appears as first set, but I don't know how to update it.

- Second issue, there must be a better way to test which pin I am dealing with. Line:

  //* I need a better test to check that this not touchPoint!

Comment: Will you share your demo, if you dont mind ? I can understand your issue and post answer of it

Comment: Fine, but let me know what you need to know that is not in my post. I have already shared all I can think of on the subject, here in the post.

Comment: check this answer I think that will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467408/swift-add-mkannotationview-to-mkmapview

Comment: Hum? But I can add an MKAnnotationView. My problem is to update the contents of the label I added, when I want.

Comment: means if you click somewhere else then you have to update your label with ?

Comment: You see the line: "self.secondPoint.title = "Hello Second -TITLE!"" ? This is where I want to update the label I added (probaly using setInfo()), but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131402/discussion-between-jecky-and-michel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the annotation view to show some text that is updated as the annotation changes, use KVO on the annotation. So, first, create a model object, the annotation, which includes the new property to be observed:

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    dynamic var title: String?
    dynamic var subtitle: String?
    dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    dynamic var information: String?

    init(title: String? = nil, subtitle: String? = nil, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, information: String? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.information = information
    }
}
```

I've called this new property `information`, but you can probably come up with a better name that captures the functional intent of this property. But hopefully it illustrates the idea. The key takeaway here is that if this property may change at a later point, we'll want to make it `dynamic` so we can use KVO to observe those changes.

```
class MyPinAnnotationView: MKPinAnnotationView {
    private let informationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 70.0, height: 30.0)))

    private var observerContext = 0

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            removeObserverIfAny()
        }
        didSet {
            if let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation {
                annotation.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(MyAnnotation.information), context: &observerContext)
                informationLabel.text = annotation.information
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        removeObserverIfAny()
    }

    private func removeObserverIfAny() {
        if let oldAnnotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation {
            oldAnnotation.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(MyAnnotation.information))
        }
    }

    func showInformation() {
        addSubview(informationLabel)
    }

    func hideInformation() {
        informationLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard context == &observerContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }

        if let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation, let information = annotation.information {
            informationLabel.text = information
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MyPinAnnotationView
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MyPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        annotationView?.showInformation()
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

I've changed the name of the label to `informationLabel` to make it a little more explicit that it is a view, not to be confused with the model property, `information`, of our new `MyAnnotation` class. Also, I'd suggest more meaningful class names than `MyAnnotation` and `MyPinAnnotationView`, perhaps using some name that better captures the functional intent of these two classes.

Regardless, as you can see, when you set the `annotation` for this annotation view, it updates the label `text`. But it also observes the annotation's new `information` property via KVO, so if this property changes later, the view will update accordingly.

Comment: No, I don't want to observe title, because of the reason you mentioned. But I will keep in mind your observer idea and see if I can do something with it. I want to update the information UILabel (See my post).

Comment: I certainly need to work, starting with your idea. I have to say, just by reading your code I don't understand much at this point. Eventually I want to update the contents of information(UILabel), when the user touches the display and secondPoint changes place. I hope what you suggest will enable me to do that, once I see how it works.

Comment: @Michel - Yeah, that's why we use observer pattern, so that you can update some annotation property at a later point and the annotation view will update accordingly. Just observe some property other than `title`. See my expanded answer above.

Comment: It was quite a bit of work but it's OK now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Works like a charm!